# Can't disable Alt + mouse buttons combinations

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, window, blender

I'm working in blender and there are some combinations that I am used to and remapping them in blender would be the last resort, not the first. I have tried to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+LMB and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RMB actions in ccsm, I've tried to do this in dconf and gconf editors as well, but nothing helped.

As soon as I close the editors or get back to the main screen of ccsm, these combinations are enabled again. So, for example, instead of selecting an edge loop in blender with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RMB, I get this annoying menu offering me to move the window to another workspace, etc.

I really don't need this function, so I'd rather switch it off instead of remapping the hotkeys I'm used to in blender.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **CCSM > General > General options**.

Go to the **Key bindings** tab.

Find the function you need changed, in your case it's **Window Menu**.

Just setting the keybinding to *disabled* doesn't seem to work. You have to set it as something else. In my system, I set it to `<Super>Button3`.